# How to break lines for the big bullet for tabular listings on a CV?

Tags: tables, cv

I’m currently writing my CV using LaTeX and had a question.

I’m using a tabular command to make large bullets on the left and list the details on the right. What I’m going for is:

[image]

But the code that I have:

```
\noindent \begin{tabular}{@{} l l}
 \Large{Contact \\ Information} & Stuff \\
 & Stuff 2 \\
\end{tabular}
```

gives me the following result:

[image]

Which isn’t quite what I want.

How could I change my code to get the first picture’s results? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are dedicated packages for typesetting CVs but as for the tabulars you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent \begin{tabular}{@{} l l}
 \Large\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
 Contact \\ Information
\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
 Stuff 1 \\ 
 Stuff 2 \\ 
 Stuff 3 \\ 
\end{tabular}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]